# Why is there a "But" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> Running the White House in a normal environment can be overwhelming. **But** the affable 44-year-old routinely finds himself rushing down the hallway from his office to intercept unscheduled visitors to the Oval Office.

If running the White house in a normal environment can be so difficult and the 44-year-old became busy because of that, then why there is a but in the beginning of the sentence? Wasn't "but" used to say when some two situations are contrary? Or Am I just misunderstanding these parts of article completely?

http://time.com/4672974/donald-trump-white-house-chaos/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Wasn't 'but' used to say when some two situations are contrary?"

Well, that is one definition. *But* another is:
[**but**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/but)

> 2. conjunction
>      You use **but** when you are about to add something further in a discussion or to change the subject.
>      *They need to recruit more people into the prison service. But another point I'd like to make is that many prisons were built in the nineteenth century.*

This definition applies to your example and my usage above.

Comment: So those two sentences don't actually contradict each other right?

Comment: Correct. The second sentence concerns how the "affable 44-year-old" deals with the environmental conditions (the additional information) but does not indicate he is the opposite of overwhelmed (underwhelmed or in control).

Comment: I often hear "But there is more to it" which adds more information to what was previously said.